# get object array from object and merge in single

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb

i need to merge data from array of object into single array, this is my current response.

```
[
  {
    "title": 'sample name of title 1',
    "isDeleted": false,
    "debates": [
      {
        "hashtag": "#hashtag",
        "debate_title_short": "debate title short 1",
        "participant": [
          {
            "participant_id": "647ad8b3874ba1c81ad8fe18",
            "participant_name": "participant name 1",
            "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d57"
          }
        ],
        "images": [
          {
            "title": "The principles of the UN Charter",
            "alt": "the principles of the UN Charter",
            "caption": "The principles of the UN Charter",
            "source": "AP",
            "filePath": "admin/wkobonygrwy0lesz_1688576125-1688625513503.webp",
            "fileName": "wkobonygrwy0lesz_1688576125-1688625513503.webp",
            "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d58"
          }
        ],
        "video_id": [
          {
            "id": "FDjFVhuE",
            "duration": "86.65599822998047",
            "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d59"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2023-07-10T14:19:58.650Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-07-10T14:19:58.650Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "title": 'sample name of title 2',
    "isDeleted": false,
    "debates": [
      {
        "hashtag": "#hashtag",
        "debate_title_short": "debate title short 2",
        "participant": [
          {
            "participant_id": "647ad8b3874ba1c81ad8fe18",
            "participant_name": "participant name 2",
            "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d57"
          }
        ],
        "images": [
          {
            "title": "The principles of the UN Charter",
            "alt": "the principles of the UN Charter",
            "caption": "The principles of the UN Charter",
            "source": "AP",
            "filePath": "admin/wkobonygrwy0lesz_1688576125-1688625513503.webp",
            "fileName": "wkobonygrwy0lesz_1688576125-1688625513503.webp",
            "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d58"
          }
        ],
        "video_id": [
          {
            "id": "FDjFVhuE",
            "duration": "86.65599822998047",
            "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d59"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2023-07-10T13:33:10.596Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-07-10T13:38:46.901Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

and this is my query for current reponse as show above

```
Data = await debate.aggregate([
  { $sort: { updatedAt: -1 } },
  { $limit : 8 },
]).exec()
```

required response is as below, i want debates array which is inside object merged in one single array of objects.

```
[
  {
    "hashtag": "#hashtag",
    "debate_title_short": "debate title short 1",
    "participant": [
      {
        "participant_id": "647ad8b3874ba1c81ad8fe18",
        "participant_name": "participant name 1",
        "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d57"
      }
    ],
    "images": [
      {
        "title": "The principles of the UN Charter",
        "alt": "the principles of the UN Charter",
        "caption": "The principles of the UN Charter",
        "source": "AP",
        "filePath": "admin/wkobonygrwy0lesz_1688576125-1688625513503.webp",
        "fileName": "wkobonygrwy0lesz_1688576125-1688625513503.webp",
        "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d58"
      }
    ],
    "video_id": [
      {
        "id": "FDjFVhuE",
        "duration": "86.65599822998047",
        "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d59"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "hashtag": "#hashtag",
    "debate_title_short": "debate title short 2",
    "participant": [
      {
        "participant_id": "647ad8b3874ba1c81ad8fe18",
        "participant_name": "participant name 2",
        "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d57"
      }
    ],
    "images": [
      {
        "title": "The principles of the UN Charter",
        "alt": "the principles of the UN Charter",
        "caption": "The principles of the UN Charter",
        "source": "AP",
        "filePath": "admin/wkobonygrwy0lesz_1688576125-1688625513503.webp",
        "fileName": "wkobonygrwy0lesz_1688576125-1688625513503.webp",
        "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d58"
      }
    ],
    "video_id": [
      {
        "id": "FDjFVhuE",
        "duration": "86.65599822998047",
        "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d59"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

here is the playground link https://mongoplayground.net/p/hWFnpUmF5Ut

can anyone help me out to achive the required response

Comment: like this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/iBvyMVIfsvm

Comment: @cmgchess thnx, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMap()`

```js
let db=[
  {
    "title": 'sample name of title 1',
    "isDeleted": false,
    "debates": [
      {
        "hashtag": "#hashtag",
        "debate_title_short": "debate title short 1",
        "participant": [
          {
            "participant_id": "647ad8b3874ba1c81ad8fe18",
            "participant_name": "participant name 1",
            "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d57"
          }
        ],
        "images": [
          {
            "title": "The principles of the UN Charter",
            "alt": "the principles of the UN Charter",
            "caption": "The principles of the UN Charter",
            "source": "AP",
            "filePath": "admin/wkobonygrwy0lesz_1688576125-1688625513503.webp",
            "fileName": "wkobonygrwy0lesz_1688576125-1688625513503.webp",
            "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d58"
          }
        ],
        "video_id": [
          {
            "id": "FDjFVhuE",
            "duration": "86.65599822998047",
            "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d59"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2023-07-10T14:19:58.650Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-07-10T14:19:58.650Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "title": 'sample name of title 2',
    "isDeleted": false,
    "debates": [
      {
        "hashtag": "#hashtag",
        "debate_title_short": "debate title short 2",
        "participant": [
          {
            "participant_id": "647ad8b3874ba1c81ad8fe18",
            "participant_name": "participant name 2",
            "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d57"
          }
        ],
        "images": [
          {
            "title": "The principles of the UN Charter",
            "alt": "the principles of the UN Charter",
            "caption": "The principles of the UN Charter",
            "source": "AP",
            "filePath": "admin/wkobonygrwy0lesz_1688576125-1688625513503.webp",
            "fileName": "wkobonygrwy0lesz_1688576125-1688625513503.webp",
            "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d58"
          }
        ],
        "video_id": [
          {
            "id": "FDjFVhuE",
            "duration": "86.65599822998047",
            "_id": "64ac138e98fc3b6e149c5d59"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2023-07-10T13:33:10.596Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-07-10T13:38:46.901Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
const output = db.flatMap(obj => obj.debates);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: thnx sai for your answer, but @cmgchess answer worked for me.